# Сохранить html файл в png

Tags: python

Подскажите как сохранить html файл в png. Я пробовал через imgkit но безуспешно.

file_test.html

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE HTML>-->
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-body ">
                <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cash glyphicon glyphicon-play text-danger" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15 4H1v8h14V4zM1 3a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v8a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h14a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H1z"></path>
                <path d="M13 4a2 2 0 0 0 2 2V4h-2zM3 4a2 2 0 0 1-2 2V4h2zm10 8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2v2h-2zM3 12a2 2 0 0 0-2-2v2h2zm7-4a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0z"></path>
                </svg>
                <h5 class="card-title">some text</h5>

                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">some text</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Пытался реализовать следующим кодом. Однако результата нет.

```
import imgkit

path_wkthmltoimage = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe'
config = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage=path_wkthmltoimage)

imgkit.from_file('file_test.html', 'file_test.jpg',config=config)
```

UPD: этот код не должен открывать браузер.

Comment: "этот код не должен открывать браузер", подключает 6 JavaScript файлов...

Comment: Да, подключаю. Потому, что это единственный вариант, при котором у меня один html файл, который я могу открыть. Можно ли такой же дизайн сделать с помощью opencv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накидал пример через [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium):

```
import time
from pathlib import Path

# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


file_name = 'file_test.html'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.set_window_size(500, 500)
driver.get('file://' + str(Path(file_name).resolve()))

time.sleep(5)

driver.save_screenshot(file_name + '.png')

driver.quit()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вариант не совсем подходит, потому что браузер открывается. Я дописал этот момент в описание вопроса.

Comment: @WilteRatenau, это не проблема. Добавил код для "безголового" запуска, теперь окно браузера не будет показано